# multiprocess and parallelism in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, scapy

I'm writing a Python script that uses scapy to do some packet sniffing and parsing. That all works pretty well, and I decided to try to get this to work as a multithreaded script to handle processing higher volumes of traffic.

The basic idea is that if scapy sees an interesting packet, throw it into a Queue, and let all of the worker grab a packet out of the Queue, process it, and go back for another one. This cycle only works once, so I'm guessing that when the script goes back to the scapy side of things, it doesn't let go.

How can I get this so that scapy continues to throw packets in the queue, and my threads can keep processing queued packets?

```
from scapy.all import *
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
max_threads=10

packetqueue=Queue(maxsize=0)

def queue_packet(packet):
        packetqueue.put(packet)

def analyze_packet(q):
        while True:
                packet=q.get()
                <do stuff to packet>
                q.task_done()

for i in range(max_threads):
        worker=Thread(target=analyze_packet,args=(packetqueue,))
        worker.setDaemon(True)
        worker.start()

sniff(iface="eth4", filter = "<filter>", store=0, prn=queue_packet)
```

Comment: Are you sure there is traffic on that interface? Can you check if [this code works for you](http://pastebin.com/84z8Nee5)?

Comment: Thanks! Your code works, but I can't see why my code doesn't and this does. I must be overlooking something very simple.

Comment: Either your filter is not matching anything, or you have a problem in `<do stuff to packet>`. NOTE: `packet.sprintf` returns a string that has to be passed to print or the equivalent if you want to see the output.